# Unity Error: Native crash of com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash-reports, native-crash-reporting

`Hello,
I recently published my unity game on the Google Play Store as an open beta. In the pre-launch report,     they showed two errors on a specific device (google pixel 2), as provided below. How can I solve theses issues?. I can't catch those issues in my scripts. I am badly in need of this solution. Thanks in advance.

**First issue:**

```
Version '2021.3.31f1 (3409e2af086f)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.033/10836537:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-12-11 07:33:46-0800
pid: 9537, tid: 9695, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner <<<
uid: 10181
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000025df  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000722dc234b0
    x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  000000762762ea00  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000762766cde4
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 000000000000eb86  x15 0000000000000030
    x16 00000076276d1d58  x17 00000076276aec70  x18 0000007227234000  x19 0000000000002541
    x20 00000000000025df  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 000000722dc24000
    x24 00000072d038cd10  x25 0000007316393000  x26 00000072d038fc80  x27 000000721000018c
    x28 0000000000002777  x29 000000722dc23530
    sp  000000722dc23490  lr  000000762765e968  pc  000000762765e994
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #01 pc 0000000000041814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #02 pc 0000000000041ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportError(char const*)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #03 pc 0000000000042220  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::stringifyAction(scudo::AllocatorAction)) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #04 pc 0000000000043a20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+308) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #05 pc 000000000001046c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+228) (BuildId: 01d06ed28f3e61881aecee6e352da587)
      #06 pc 000000000001cb5c  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+44) (BuildId: f7b27cec8464273f3f930678324abd0d)
      #07 pc 00000000008e6550  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #08 pc 00000000008e5c34  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #09 pc 00000000008e5b44  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #10 pc 000000000039c078  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #11 pc 000000000039c014  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #12 pc 0000000000609ba4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #13 pc 000000000073ebf8  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #14 pc 000000000073f7d4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #15 pc 0000000000736b5c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #16 pc 000000000028e480  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #17 pc 00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #18 pc 00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
```

**Second Issue:**

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.033/10836537:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-12-11 07:33:46.512332225-0800
Process uptime: 17s
Cmdline: com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner
pid: 9537, tid: 9695, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner <<<
uid: 10181
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
pac_enabled_keys: 000000000000000f (PR_PAC_APIAKEY, PR_PAC_APIBKEY, PR_PAC_APDAKEY, PR_PAC_APDBKEY)
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when deallocating address 0x2000073b5cea920'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000025df  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000722dc234b0
    x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  000000762762ea00  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000762766cde4
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 000000000000eb86  x15 0000000000000030
    x16 00000076276d1d58  x17 00000076276aec70  x18 0000007227234000  x19 0000000000002541
    x20 00000000000025df  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 000000722dc24000
    x24 00000072d038cd10  x25 0000007316393000  x26 00000072d038fc80  x27 000000721000018c
    x28 0000000000002777  x29 000000722dc23530
    lr  000000762765e968  sp  000000722dc23490  pc  000000762765e994  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #01 pc 0000000000041814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+8) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #02 pc 0000000000041ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::ScopedErrorReport::~ScopedErrorReport()+32) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #03 pc 0000000000042220  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportInvalidChunkState(scudo::AllocatorAction, void*)+116) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #04 pc 0000000000043a20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+308) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #05 pc 000000000001046c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+228) (BuildId: 01d06ed28f3e61881aecee6e352da587)
      #06 pc 000000000001cb5c  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+44) (BuildId: f7b27cec8464273f3f930678324abd0d)
      #07 pc 00000000008e6550  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #08 pc 00000000008e5c34  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #09 pc 00000000008e5b44  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #10 pc 000000000039c078  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #11 pc 000000000039c014  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #12 pc 0000000000609ba4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #13 pc 000000000073ebf8  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #14 pc 000000000073f7d4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #15 pc 0000000000736b5c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #16 pc 000000000028e480  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #17 pc 00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #18 pc 00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
Second Issue:
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emu64a:13/TE1A.220922.033/10836537:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-12-11 07:33:46.512332225-0800
Process uptime: 17s
Cmdline: com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner
pid: 9537, tid: 9695, name: UnityGfxDeviceW  >>> com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner <<<
uid: 10181
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
pac_enabled_keys: 000000000000000f (PR_PAC_APIAKEY, PR_PAC_APIBKEY, PR_PAC_APDAKEY, PR_PAC_APDBKEY)
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: invalid chunk state when deallocating address 0x2000073b5cea920'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000025df  x2  0000000000000006  x3  000000722dc234b0
    x4  0000000000808080  x5  0000000000808080  x6  0000000000808080  x7  8080808080808080
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  000000762762ea00  x10 0000000000000001  x11 000000762766cde4
    x12 0101010101010101  x13 000000007fffffff  x14 000000000000eb86  x15 0000000000000030
    x16 00000076276d1d58  x17 00000076276aec70  x18 0000007227234000  x19 0000000000002541
    x20 00000000000025df  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000000000000000  x23 000000722dc24000
    x24 00000072d038cd10  x25 0000007316393000  x26 00000072d038fc80  x27 000000721000018c
    x28 0000000000002777  x29 000000722dc23530
    lr  000000762765e968  sp  000000722dc23490  pc  000000762765e994  pst 0000000000001000
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #01 pc 0000000000041814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+8) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #02 pc 0000000000041ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::ScopedErrorReport::~ScopedErrorReport()+32) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #03 pc 0000000000042220  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportInvalidChunkState(scudo::AllocatorAction, void*)+116) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #04 pc 0000000000043a20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+308) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #05 pc 000000000001046c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+228) (BuildId: 01d06ed28f3e61881aecee6e352da587)
      #06 pc 000000000001cb5c  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+44) (BuildId: f7b27cec8464273f3f930678324abd0d)
      #07 pc 00000000008e6550  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #08 pc 00000000008e5c34  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #09 pc 00000000008e5b44  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #10 pc 000000000039c078  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #11 pc 000000000039c014  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #12 pc 0000000000609ba4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #13 pc 000000000073ebf8  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #14 pc 000000000073f7d4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #15 pc 0000000000736b5c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #16 pc 000000000028e480  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CodeCraftedMind.ExtremeCityRunner-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 129539ef2cab1bebe2d18907d70c12d8ac763d94)
      #17 pc 00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
      #18 pc 00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 01331f74b0bb2cb958bdc15282b8ec7b)
`
```

Comment: [Problem got solved]: Hello, everyone who is struggling with this error or facing this issue. Just follow this instruction: From your unity Editor go to=> Player Settings=Uncheck=>'Optimized Frame Pacing'. And then build your aab file again and do publish.